# Change TrackBallControls Panning from XY to XZ

Tags: webgl, three.js

How do I change TrackBallControls to pan on X and Z plane
instead of the X and Y plane?

I see that now it uses the cross of the up vector of the camera and mouseChange vector...

Comment: Nevermind... I figured it out!

changed: 
pan.addSelf( _this.object.up.clone().setLength( mouseChange.y ) );
to:
pan.addSelf( _eye.clone().setY(0).setLength( - mouseChange.y ) );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question:

Changed:

```
pan.addSelf( _this.object.up.clone().setLength( mouseChange.y ) );
```

to:

```
pan.addSelf( _eye.clone().setY(0).setLength( -mouseChange.y ) );
```